# How to send dbachecks output to a file on disk?

Tags: sql-server, dbachecks

How do you send the dbachecks output to a file on disk?

I tried the following but it resulted with the output on screen and a 0 kb file on disk.

```
Invoke-DbcCheck -Check Database -SqlInstance myserver -ExcludeCheck TestLastBackup, TestLastBackupVerifyOnly | Out-File c:\myserver.txt
```

Comment: `-OutputFile ...` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parameter

```
-PassThru
```

As per the [documentation](https://dbachecks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/Invoke-DbcCheck/#-passthru):

> By default, Invoke-DbcCheck writes to the host program, not to the
> output stream (stdout). If you try to save the result in a variable,
> the variable is empty unless you use the PassThru parameter.

Comment: That only partially works.  It shows the test result but truncates after about 2k characters and ends with "..."